# Compare File headers using Awk or Cmp

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have many flat files in 1 directory.
Each file has a header and some data in it.
I want to compare header of one file with all the other files available in that directory.
This can be achieved using shell scripting but i want to do it using a single line code.
I tried it using the [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) command but it is comparing the whole file not just the header.

```
for i in `ls -1 *a*` ; do cmp a.dat $i ; done
```

Can someone please let me know how can i do that? 
Also if it can be achieved using `awk`.

I just need to check whether the header is matching or not.

Comment: `i want to do it using a single line code` - why? That's a statement that will make most experienced programmers' skin crawl. Newlines are surprisingly inexpensive and some say appropriate white space actually makes code clearer. Edit your question to include concise, testable and truly representative sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

I would try this: grab the first line of every file, extract the unique lines, and count them. The result should be one.

```
number_uniq=$( sed '1q' * | sort -u | wc -l )
```

That won't tell you *which* file is different.

```
files=(*)
reference_header=$( sed '1q' "${files[0]}" )
for file in "${files[@]:1}"; do
    if [[ "$reference_header" != "$( sed '1q' "$file" )" ]]; then
        echo "wrong header: $file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Interesting. When the OP said each file has "a header" it never even occurred to me that that would mean the header was always a single line. I was imagining some kind of file or function prologue block of comments. I guess we'll know more when the OP clues us in.

Answer (score 0):

For what you describe, you can use `md5` or `cksum` to take a signature of the bytes in the header.

Given 5 files (note that `File 4.txt` does not match):

```
$ for fn in *.txt; do echo "$fn:"; cat "$fn"; printf "\n\n"; done
File 1.txt:
what a great ride! it is a lovely day
/tmp/files/File 1.txt

File 2.txt:
what a great ride! it is a lovely day
/tmp/files/File 2.txt

File 3.txt:
what a great ride! it is a lovely day
/tmp/files/File 3.txt

File 4.txt:
what an awful ride! it is a horrible day
/tmp/files/File 4.txt

reference.txt:
what a great ride! it is a lovely day
/tmp/files/reference.txt
```

You can use `md5` to get a signature and the check if they other files are the same.

First get the reference signature:

```
$ sig=$(head -1 reference.txt | md5)
$ echo $sig
549560de062a87ec69afff37abe18d8f
```

Then loop through the files:

```
for fn in *.txt; do    
  if [[ "$sig" != "$(head -1 "$fn" | md5)" ]]; then 
     echo "header of \"$fn\" does not match"; 
  fi; 
done
```

Prints:

```
header of "File 4.txt" does not match
```